# ZF2 skeleton application is throwing 500 error

Tags: deployment, zend-framework2

When trying to deploy the skeleton application using the following commands:

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
cd ZendSkeletonApplication
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

I get the following error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\\ServiceManager\\Exception\\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Provided abstract factory must be the class name of an abstract factory or an instance of an AbstractFactoryInterface.' in /home/web/www/zftests/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:302\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/web/www/zftests/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/Config.php(126): Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager->addAbstractFactory('Zend\\Cache\\Serv...')\n#1 /home/web/www/zftests/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/Listener/ServiceListener.php(223): Zend\\ServiceManager\\Config->configureServiceManager(Object(Zend\\ServiceManager\\ServiceManager))\n#2 [internal function]: Zend\\ModuleManager\\Listener\\ServiceListener->onLoadModulesPost(Object(Zend\\ModuleManager\\ModuleEvent))\n#3 /home/web/www/zftests/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library in /home/web/www/zftests/ZendSkeletonApplication/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php on line 302`

Comment: It seems the current state of the ZF2 project is broken, because several people are having the same problem currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked just fine.  The problem is that there are two files missing from the ZF2.5 Framework.

```
  'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
  'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
```

Thanks, Gary

Answer (score 2):

Please comment the following lines found in module/Application/config/module.config.php

```
      'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
      'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
```

The skeleton app will work.

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively you can use the 2.1 series of ZFSkeletonApp here.

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/tree/zf/release-2.1.0

This bug is discussed here

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/commit/80884b7da866f5136654c83604c1270a3228b7b9

Comment: I'm totaly new to Zend and try to run skeletop app - this worked, but won't commenting these 2 lines crash sth in deeper work of Zend?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks alot everybody!
Looks like the solution for now is to clone the 2.1 tag, as @weierophinney mentioned here: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/commit/80884b7da866f5136654c83604c1270a3228b7b9

```
git clone -b "zf/release-2.1.0" https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git ./
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```