# Unable to start Zend2 skeleton app

Tags: php, xampp, zend-framework2

I have a xampp serwer on windows XP:
Apache 2.4.3
PHP 5.4.7

and I try to start learning Zend2.

I downloaded skeleton app: https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication
and run from cmd:

```
php composer.phar self-update
php composer.phar install
```

(not that I had to give a full link to php like C:\xxx\php.exe - I don't know why, I have php in my enviromental variables). It went ok - no errors.

I added this code to httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added this line to C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

When I run

```
http://zf2-tutorial.localhost
```

in the browser I get "Permission denied"

When I try

```
http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/
```

I get very long php error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Provided abstract factory must be the class name of an abstract factory or an instance of an AbstractFactoryInterface.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:302 ...........
```

I figure sth is wrong with serwer since I get "Permission denied".
What I am doing wrong? Thx in advance.

BIg Thanx Everyone. My final config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost
```

Works fine on: http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/

Comment: Please see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359394/zf2-skeleton-application-is-throwing-500-error

Comment: Thanx. This solved the problem with starting the skeleton app but I can only run it on `http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/` any idea why the vhosts don't work for `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost`

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. But it appears to be a bug, found this https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4403 on the github issue tracker for zf2 (comment from weierophinney) We'll just have to wait for a fix, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosts file is incorrect. Instead of:

```
127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost localhost
```

Remove the last "localhost", so you get:

```
127.0.0.1               zf2-tutorial.localhost
```

Edit:
Another thing I just noticed is your DocumentRoot: this should be the fully qualified path to your document root: i.e. C:/www/zf-tutorial/public. Note that you should use forward slashes for directory separators. Use the same path in your Directory configuration to make sure that access is allowed to that directory.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Unfortunatelly it didn't work. Now I get permission denied on both `http://zf2-tutorial.localhost`  and `http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/public/`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Windows, so your vhost configuration should contains Windows alike path to your project. Are you sure that you have valid path to php\bin in your %PATH%?

```
> echo %PATH%
```

I am using XAMPP on Windows 7.
Here is my vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/projects/zf2-tutorial/public"
    ServerName zf2.tutorial
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory C:/xampp/projects/zf2-tutorial/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/zf2.tutorial-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/zf2.tutorial-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This one is essential (probably also in your case):

```
    <Directory C:/xampp/projects/zf2-tutorial/public>
        # ...
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```