# Zend Framework 2 error

Tags: php, zend-framework2

After a `composer update` my application don't run anymore.
The error is:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Provided abstract factory must be the class name of an abstract factory or an instance of an AbstractFactoryInterface.' in /path_to_app/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:302

I googled the error and seems that in may 2013 happened something similar that could be [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16359394/zf2-skeleton-application-is-throwing-500-error) just commenting two lines in the module.config.php 
Naturally, I've tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have a factory service configuration issue in your module.config.php, like the error says one of your configured factory services is not a "class name of an abstract factory or an instance of an AbstractFactoryInterface.".

For debugging purpose, try to temporarily disable your application registered modules one by one to detect in which module this is configured (if you have no idea), until the error disappear.

Then check the services configs.

Comment: I tried (disabled all modules in application.config.php) but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you post you application.config.php?